# Using 2 same Recursion to do 2 different things

Tags: php, jquery, html, recursion

I was trying to show `tree` data with `JQuery` **expand and collapse**.

```
For example my database 
Parent A has AA, AB, AC children
Parent AA has AAA, AAB, AAC
Parent AC has ACA, ACB, ACD
etc.
```

So I am using Recursion to show all the data from the database.

But I also need to declare the JQuery, so I am using the same `Recursion` code to generate the script

What I want to ask is, is there any way to use the Recursion one time to generate both things?, the data show inside the `<body>` tag, and JQuery declare at `<head>` tag.

Because I feel it will waste the memory to do same thing 2 times.

This is my `<body>` code

```
   <?   
      $temp = "";                
      $parent = "";
      $level = 0;
      loadFolders($parent, $level, $temp);

      function loadFolders($parent, $level, $temp){
        $getLevelSql = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parent' and level='$level'");
        $level++;
        while ($getLevelSqlRow = mysql_fetch_array($getLevelSql)){
          $parentID = $getLevelSqlRow['id'];
          $child = $getLevelSqlRow['child'];
          $checkChild = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parentID' and level='$level' ");
          if (mysql_num_rows($checkChild)){
          ?>
            <div class="level1 redFont" id="levelID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>">
              <?echo "$child";?>
            </div>  
            <div class="level2" id="childID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>">
          <?
            loadFolders($parentID, $level, $temp);
          ?>
            </div>
          <?  
          } else {
          ?>
            <div><?echo "$child";?></div>  
          <?
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

This is my `<head>` code

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

    <?
      include "config.php";
      $temp = "";                
      $parent = "";
      $level = 0;
      loadFolder($parent, $level, $temp);

      function loadFolder($parent, $level, $temp){
        $getLevelSql = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parent' and level='$level'");
        $level++;
        while ($getLevelSqlRow = mysql_fetch_array($getLevelSql)){
          $parentID = $getLevelSqlRow['id'];
          $child = $getLevelSqlRow['child'];
          $checkChild = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parentID' and level='$level' ");
          if (mysql_num_rows($checkChild)){
          ?>
            $("#levelID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>").click(function(){
            $("#childID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>").slideToggle("slow");
          });
          <?
            loadFolder($parentID, $level, $temp);
          ?>
          <?  
          }
        }
      }
    ?>

    });
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is a really complicated way to go about it..

Comment: @Ben Yeah, or is it the only way to do it?, I just want to save the memory consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this as I haven't got data to do it but basically you really just need to use selectors in your jquery code to find the sub section from any of the click point.

I would nest the child element to make it easier. Something like this:

```
   <?   
  $temp = "";                
  $parent = "";
  $level = 0;
  loadFolders($parent, $level, $temp);

  function loadFolders($parent, $level, $temp){
    $getLevelSql = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parent' and level='$level'");
    $level++;
    while ($getLevelSqlRow = mysql_fetch_array($getLevelSql)){
      $parentID = $getLevelSqlRow['id'];
      $child = $getLevelSqlRow['child'];
      $checkChild = mysql_query("select * from folders where parent='$parentID' and level='$level' ");
      if (mysql_num_rows($checkChild)){
        // ** notice I've added item class and nested the children inside
      ?>
        <div class="level1 redFont item" id="levelID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>">
          <?echo "$child";?>
          <div class="children" id="childID<?echo $getLevelSqlRow['id'];?>">
        </div>  

      <?
        loadFolders($parentID, $level, $temp);
      ?>
        </div>
      <?  
      } else {
      ?>
        <div><?echo "$child";?></div>  
      <?
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Then your jquery becomes something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.item').click(function(){
        $(this).find('>div.children').slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

No need to loop twice and generate a hundred handlers..

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it will end up expand all the `tags` with **children** class. I have a lot of data, and all data have different levels

Comment: @Sieryuu `>` means direct children

Comment: It didn't work, I have changed the class and change the `JQuery`

Comment: Try to console.log things inside the handler and try to work out the correct selector..

Comment: the child is not the `children` tag of the `parent` tag. It is just below the `parent` tag. for example, <div>parent</div><div>child</div>. what ">" means <div>parent<div>child</div></div> rite?

Comment: @Sieryuu. See the comment in the updated PHP code. I've moved it to make it easier. But if you don't want to do that, you can use [jQuery's `next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select instead

Comment: Yeah, I am going to use `next()`. Thanks